# Insert pages into PDF

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, itext

Is there any function like `Document.InsertPage(pageIndex)`? Or any alternative solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is [PdfStamper.insertPage(int, Rectangle)](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfStamper.html#insertPage%28int,%20com.itextpdf.text.Rectangle%29).

See a full example of how to use it [here](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=120), but in short, it should boil down to:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest));

stamper.insertPage(pageIndex, reader.getPageSizeWithRotation(1));

// insert content via stamper.getUnderContent() or stamper.getOverContent()

stamper.close();
reader.close();
```

Note that this is Java code, but the C# counterpart can be deduced quite easily.